# Why script not showing at footer section in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add jquery to my wordpress theme. I have used this code

```
function theme_name_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery',true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

But it is showing at head section . Not in footer section. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery',true);
```

With this

```
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', false, null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

All that is saying is load the the JS file called jQuery that can be found in the 'js' folder of your theme folder.

Although I would always load in Google's CDN version as recommended here:

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you could try putting a number at the end of the function line...like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery',true,11);
```

**EDIT**
Maybe try this approach: [How can I include Jquery in my Wordpress footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344070/how-can-i-include-jquery-in-my-wordpress-footer)

Answer (score 0):

> Why script not showing at footer section in wordpress?

Because it's already registered for `header`, by default, `WordPress` does it.

You may use (an easy workaround)

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js','','',true);
```

You can't omit optional parameters like you did in here `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery',true);` and following won't work

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','','','',true);
```

Also remember that, this (`$in_footer`, to put the script in footer) requires the theme to have the [wp_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) template tag in the appropriate place. Read [this article](http://blog.cloudfour.com/getting-all-javascript-into-the-footer-in-wordpress-not-so-fast-buster/).

Also, you may use

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script(
    'jquery',
    // you can use "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" for latest version
    /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js,
    false,
    false,
    true
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Also, check [this generator](http://generatewp.com/register_script/), it gave me following code generated by options I've chosen

```
// Register Script
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', false, false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
// Hook into the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

You can generate your own code using this tool very easily.